# RegExp to search words starts with numbers and special characters only using C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to perform a search to C# list object to find all products starts with any number or special characters only. I am looking for a Regular expressions for this scenario.

Please help

Comment: What kind of list is it?

Comment: its a list of Product Names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you list is a list of string:

```
var newList = yourList.Where(element => Regex.IsMatch(element, @"^[^a-z]", RegexOption.IgnoreCase);
```

It will give you a sublist of all the elements that doesn't start with a letter in the range `a-z`.